# How to reshape a csv table in R?

Tags: r, reshape

I have this dataset:

```
   Group Group Group Cat Cat Cat  Betw
1      a               A          5.87
2      b           j   A          0.11
3      c               B       A  2.18
4      d               C   D      5.31
5      e               E   C      0.00
6      f               E         352.10
7      g               E          0.35
8      h               A   B      0.00
9      i     m         F          0.00
10     j               A   D      15.04
```

Which I would like to reshape so that there is only 3 columns : Var1 (which would be 'Group' or 'Cat'), Var2 (which would have a lower case or uppercase letter) and Betw.

So for instance, c, b and A all have a value of 2.1892749,

```
   Var1 Var2  Betw
1 Group    a  5.87
2   Cat    A  5.87
3 Group    b  0.11
4 Group    j  0.11
5   Cat    A  0.11
...
```

How to do this with R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess directly applying `melt` doesn't work for you because of the duplicated column names in the data frame. So along the lines of @akrun, you can use something like this

```
tmp <- data.frame(df, check.names=T)
tmp <- melt(tmp, id="Betw", variable.name="Var1", value.name="Var2")
tmp$Var1 <- gsub("(.*)\\.[0-9]", "\\1", tmp$Var1)
df <- subset(tmp, Var2!="")
```

The data frame I used,

```
df <- data.frame(Group=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"),
                 Group=c("","","","","","","","","m",""),
                 Group=c("","j","","","","","","","",""),
                 Cat=c("A","A","B","C","E","E","E","A","F","A"),
                 Cat=c("","","","D","C","","","B","","D"),
                 Cat=c("","","A","","","","","","",""),
                 Betw=c(5.87,0.11,2.18,5.31,0,352.1,0.35,0,0,15.04),
                 check.names = F)
```

Answer (score 2):

We could also use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dat)`, reshape to long format with `melt`, delete the rows that are blank for 'Var2', and remove the substring in 'Var1' that starts with `.` to the end of the string (if present).

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
melt(setDT(dat), id.var='Betw', variable.name='Var1', 
        value.name='Var2')[Var2!=''][, Var1:= sub('\\..*', '', Var1)][]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` and `tidyr`. First we `gather` to long data, then remove the extra numbers put onto the columns, then we remove the blanks:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% gather(Var1, Var2, -Betw) %>%
        mutate(Var1 = gsub(".[0-9]$", "", Var1)) %>%
        filter(Var2 != "")
```

data used:

```
structure(list(Group = structure(1:10, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), class = "factor"), Group.1 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "m"), class = "factor"), 
    Group.2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("", "j"), class = "factor"), Cat = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", 
    "C", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), Cat.1 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("", "B", 
    "C", "D"), class = "factor"), Cat.2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "A"), class = "factor"), 
    Betw = c(5.87, 0.11, 2.18, 5.31, 0, 352.1, 0.35, 0, 0, 15.04
    )), .Names = c("Group", "Group.1", "Group.2", "Cat", "Cat.1", 
"Cat.2", "Betw"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```